# Run batch file in ScriptBlock called from Start-Job command

Tags: powershell, start-job, scriptblock

Trying to run a batch file and sending a parameter from ScriptBlock. And I am calling ScriptBlock from Start-Job command

```
$ScriptBlock = {
        param($file)
        E:\test\test.bat $file
    }

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock  -ArgumentList $file
```

What should I do to run that test.bat file from ScriptBlock

Comment: would that be in quotes like "cmd /c E:\test\test.bat" coz its running

Comment: If your batch file is running, then what is your question?

Comment: Thanks for help Ryan, now its running